# C# Create and change class at runtime

Tags: c#

Assume that I'm receiving endless stream of "anonymous" objects as (JSON/XML/whatever) that are supposed to be of same class, however not all objects contains all fields/properties, ex:

```
{
 object1 : {field1 : 1, field2: 2},
 object2 : {field1 : 3, field4: 5}
}
```

As you can see if I use either of objects as template and create a class matching it, the other one won't fit as there's a missing property, in the case of limited objects I can go over them and extract all fields then build a class that fits all and default the missing properties for each object.

However in an "endless" stream it's not possible to do it, so the only approach I found is creating Class1 that fits the first object and create the first object, when going to next object if there's an extra property I add it to Class1 and create the second object of Class1, then go again for each object. When Editing Class1 all objects that were made before the edit must include the new property without having to recreate them.

Any idea how to do this??

Note: I don't want to create a new class every time I find a new field, it'll take much time to recreate all old objects not to mention that number of objects is ever increasing.

Comment: Why do you need concrete classes at all, wouldn't something more dynamic fit your needs better, like a dictionary or expandoobject or something?

Comment: Don't declare any class. Use `JObject.Parse("...")` (in Json.Net). Now you have your object with all properties in it.

Comment: What if you use `Dictionary<string, object> allProperties` to store your properties like `allProperties.Add("field1", 1); allProperties.Add("field4", 5);` ?

Comment: @Eser I'm doing "manual" parsing.
@Lasse V. Karlsen expandoobject gives error when trying to access a "property" that doesn't exist while I want to make it return default value for it depending on the type of property, I thought of something like a dictionary but I want to be able to access it like normal property/field with `object.property`

Comment: @Fabjan Accessing a "field" that doesn't exist will give error, I want it to return default value depending on type. also want to access them as in `object.property` style

Comment: @T.Aoukar the 'I want' plant doesn't even grow in the king's garden

Comment: This problem *begs* for a `DynamicProxy` based solution...

Comment: Try to improve your title man.... something like "deserialise heterogeneous array of objects" would do the trick... you don't wanna go for a big headline for something so meaning less, that could easily be solved with JSON NET / Expando Object / Dynamic Proxy... and by the way... if the expando object gives you error when trying to access a non existing property, it doesn't mean that you can't override the getter method so it won't throw an exception...

Comment: Well, *somewhere* you need to declare or state or list all the expected fields and their expected type. The alternative would be to first read through all the objects, gather unique property names with their types and then build a data structure for that that could return default values for objects/elements that are missing some of the properties.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen I'm actually looking into declaring those in a class and save it to .dll file, the alternative isn't possible since in theory I have endless stream and holding it all isn't an option at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library's JObect class.

1- You can use it with `dynamic`

```
string json1 = @"{object1 : {field1 : 1, field2: 2}}";
string json2 = @"{object2 : {field3 : 3, field2: 4}}";

dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json2);
if (obj.object1 != null) Console.WriteLine(obj.object1.field1);
if (obj.object2 != null) Console.WriteLine(obj.object2.field3);
```

2- You can use it as dictionary

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json1);
if (jObj["object1"] != null) Console.WriteLine(jObj["object1"]["field1"]);
```

3- It supports Linq. You can enumerate it easily to get all children/descendants etc.

```
var rootProperties = jObj.Children().OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'm doing "manual" parsing, aka: I'm not using JSON.NET thus I don't have access to JObject.

Comment: @T.Aoukar: Can't you start using JSON.NET?